# How to add taxonomy ID to its slug in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I register a custom post type and its taxonomy as bellow:

```
function book() {
    register_post_type('book', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Book'),
            'add_new_item' => "Add New",
            'edit_item' => __('Edit'),
            'new_item' => __('New'),
            'all_items' => __('All'),
            'view_item' => __('View'),
            'search_items' => __('Search'),
            'not_found' => __('Not found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Not anything found in the Trash'),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicy_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        //'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/image.png', __FILE__ ),
        //'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book-alt3',
        'hierarchical' => TRUE,
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'
        ),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'book', 'with_front' => false),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
        'can_export' => true,
        'description' => __('Book')
            )
    );
}

function book_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
            'book_categories', //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces). 
            'book', //post type name
            array(
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'label' => 'Book Cat', //Display name
                'query_var' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'book/c', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                    'with_front' => false // Don't display the category base before 
                )
            )
        );
    }
add_action('init', 'book');
add_action('init', 'book_taxonomy');
```

This code working.
The Taxonomy link is like: 
http://localhost/ebook/book/c/book-1/
But I just want to add taxonomy ID into that link like:
http://localhost/ebook/book/c/121/book-1/
With "121" is taxonomy link.
Is there anyway to do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: $field
    (string) (required) Either 'id', 'slug', 'name', or 'term_taxonomy_id'

        Default: 'id'

Answer (score 0):

**Gives you term slug: e.g.: term-slug-example**

```
$slug = $term->slug;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I used this plugin and I can change total link in Catgory . https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/